# Geodjango-query with distance lookupsss

Tags: python, geodjango

I want to sort my result based on the distance calculated in the geodjango query.
I tried with two methods but they are throwing errors.

models.py

```
class Partner(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 location = models.PointField(u"longitude/latitude",geography=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

**method 1:**

```
testing = Partner.objects.filter(location__distance_lte=(pnt, D(km=40))).annotate(distance=Distance('location', pnt)).order_by('distance')
print(testing)
```

Error:

```
Internal Server Error: /partner/filter/
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
 response = get_response(request)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "/home/prasanna/Projects/partner_server/partner/views.py", line 79, in Filter_function
 print(testing.annotate(distance=Distance('location', pnt)).order_by('distance'))
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

**method 2:**

```
testing = Partner.objects.filter(location__distance_lte=(pnt, D(km=40))).annotate(distance=Distance('location', pnt)).order_by('distance')
print(testing)
```

Error:

```
Internal Server Error: /partner/filter/
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
 response = get_response(request)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "/home/prasanna/Projects/partner_server/partner/views.py", line 79, in Filter_function
 print(testing.distance(pnt).order_by('distance'))
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'distance'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is correct but i think you missed something or you mixed between two types of Distance and the first one usage is different from the second one.

this one is a **Measurement Object**
1- `from django.contrib.gis.measure import Distance`

and this one is one of**Geographic Database Functions**
2-`from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance`

the second one will iterate over every object (row in db) in a comparison manner that the annotate function understands,however the first function is only a basic measurement function that cannot iterate or behave as comparison function

you can refer to django docs and see the difference

Measurement : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/measure/

DB Function : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions.Distance